# Find files with include and exclude flags

Tags: bash, find

Suppose I have a directory with a bunch of files:

```
/file1.png
/directory1/file1.png
/directory1/file2.png
/directory1/file3.txt
/file2.txt
/directory2/file1.png
/directory2/file2.txt
/directory2/file3.gif
```

Is there a way you can recursively traverse the directories looking for files using `--include` and `--exclude`?

It would be great to find something as simply as:

```
find . --include "*.png" --exclude "file1.png"
```

Comment: For this simple case `find . -name "*.png" '!' -name "file1.png"` -- note the quoting of `!` is not always needed but simpler to play it safe. For more complicated cases you can do full Boolean logic using `-a -o ( )` (where bottom-level `-a` can be implicit as here) as described on the man page; again `( )` usually need quoting.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I suggest to make your comment an answer

Answer (score 2):

To exclude a file, either use a more restrictive regex than *.png or grep the output to exclude a result:

```
find . -name "*.png" | grep -v "file1.png"
```

You can exclude a whole directory tree by using the `-prune` option, but it doesn't exclude on a file level.

Comment: I've never seen a `find` that takes `--include` or in fact any double-hyphen; ITYM `-name` or maybe `-path` but those take a _pattern_ not a regex; your example `"*.png"` is a (properly quoted) pattern and not a regex. Some `find`s do take `-regex` with an actual regex.

Comment: You're right, I was just quoting some of the original post without checking too much. I'll edit to correct it.